# Monitoring Traces for Satisfaction of Temporal Logic Properties

Tags: algorithm, haskell, stream

I am trying to implement a monitor for a certain temporal logic. What this means is the following:

- There is some external source, from which a trace of items are coming. An item looks like a timestamp along with some propositions which holds at that point.
- There is a property of traces we care about. This is specified in some temporal logic. This could look like "So far, p has been true" or "Since q happened in the last two time units, r has always held since then", or "p always holds when q does"
- Our task is to build a monitor which is a streaming algorithm whose interface is the operation `step` which consumes an item from the trace and checks whether the trace fed so far satisfies the given property or not.

Here is the Haskell code:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Map
import qualified Data.Set
import Data.Maybe

-- in what follows, `t` stands for some time domain. For most purposes, we assume it is totally ordered and has subtraction defined on it.

data Interval t =
    OpenOpen t t
  | OpenClosed t t
  | ClosedOpen t t
  | ClosedClosed t t
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

inInterval :: Ord t => t -> Interval t -> Bool
inInterval t (OpenOpen       s f) = s < t && t < f
inInterval t (OpenClosed     s f) = s < t && t <= f
inInterval t (ClosedOpen     s f) = s <= t && t < f
inInterval t (ClosedClosed   s f) = s <= t && t <= f

inleqInterval :: Ord t => t -> Interval t -> Bool
inleqInterval t (OpenOpen       s f) = t < f
inleqInterval t (OpenClosed     s f) = t <= f
inleqInterval t (ClosedOpen     s f) = t < f
inleqInterval t (ClosedClosed   s f) = t <= f

-- Below, we use `prop` to denote a domain for the symbols that represent propositions
-- For most purposes, we'd want to use something like int since we'd use formulae based on this symbols as indices of maps

type TruthAssignment prop = Data.Set.Set prop
type Item t prop = (t, TruthAssignment prop)
type Trace t prop = [Item t prop] -- the programmer should ensure that the timestamps are increasing

data TemporalFormula t prop =
  Proposition prop
  | Since (Interval t) (TemporalFormula t prop) (TemporalFormula t prop)
  | Neg (TemporalFormula t prop)
  | And (TemporalFormula t prop) (TemporalFormula t prop)
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

isTemporal :: TemporalFormula t prop -> Bool
isTemporal (Since _ _ _) = True
isTemporal _ = False

getTemporalSubformulas :: TemporalFormula t prop -> [TemporalFormula t prop]
getTemporalSubformulas phi@(Since _ phi1 phi2) = [phi] ++ getTemporalSubformulas phi1 ++ getTemporalSubformulas phi2
getTemporalSubformulas (Neg phi)                 = getTemporalSubformulas phi
getTemporalSubformulas (And phi1 phi2)           = (getTemporalSubformulas phi1) ++ (getTemporalSubformulas phi2)
getTemporalSubformulas _                         = []

type MonitorState t prop = Data.Map.Map (TemporalFormula t prop) [t]

-- the following type signature says that the monitor is a stateful object which when given a stream of items produces a stream of booleans
monitor :: (Ord t, Ord prop, Num t) => TemporalFormula t prop -> Trace t prop -> State (MonitorState t prop) [Bool]
monitor phi stream = do
  iinit phi
  loop stream
  where
    loop (i:is) = do
      b <- step i phi
      bs <- loop is
      return (b:bs)
    loop []     = return []

iinit :: (Ord t, Ord prop) => TemporalFormula t prop -> State (MonitorState t prop) ()
iinit phi = do
  let subformulas = getTemporalSubformulas phi
  put $ foldr (\psi map -> Data.Map.insert psi [] map) Data.Map.empty subformulas

step :: (Num t, Ord t, Ord prop) => Item t prop -> TemporalFormula t prop -> State (MonitorState t prop) Bool
step (_, truths) (Proposition p) = return $ Data.Set.member p truths
step item (Neg formula) = not <$> step item formula
step item (And formula1 formula2) = do
  b1 <- step item formula1
  b2 <- step item formula2
  return $ b1 && b2
step item@(tao, _) phi@(Since inter phi1 phi2) = do
  update item phi
  bufffs <- get
  let lphi = case (Data.Map.lookup phi bufffs) of Just l -> l
  case lphi of
    []    -> return False
    (t:_) -> return $ inInterval (tao - t) inter

update :: (Num t, Ord t, Ord prop) => Item t prop -> TemporalFormula t prop -> State (MonitorState t prop) ()
update (time, truths) phi@(Since inter phi1 phi2) = do
  bufffs <- get
  let lphi = case (Data.Map.lookup phi bufffs) of Just l -> l
  b1 <- step (time, truths) phi1
  b2 <- step (time, truths) phi2
  let l = if b1 then (ddrop lphi inter time) else []
  let lphi' = if b2 then l ++ [time] else l
  put (Data.Map.insert phi lphi' bufffs)


ddrop :: (Ord t, Num t) => [t] -> Interval t -> t -> [t]
ddrop [] _ _             = []
ddrop (kappa:ls) inter tao
  | inleqInterval (tao - kappa) inter   = ddrop' kappa ls inter tao
  | otherwise                       = ddrop ls inter tao

ddrop' :: (Ord t, Num t) => t -> [t] -> Interval t -> t -> [t]
ddrop' kappa [] _ _          = [kappa]
ddrop' kappa (kappa':ls) inter tao
  | inInterval (tao - kappa') inter    = ddrop' kappa' ls inter tao
  | otherwise                          = (kappa:kappa':ls)
```

For comparison, here is a [Java implementation](https://github.com/Agnishom/pltlmonitors/tree/master/pltl-java) of the same idea.

I would like some feedback on my Haskell code:

- I would like to be able to extend this code with a `main` and test it on a large stream to see how well it **performs**. Is the State Monad appropriate for the purpose of performance? Is my way of modelling streams as lists appropriate for this purpose?
- As implemented, the "monitor state" and the Formula looks like independent objects. Is there a better way to tie them together than to define a seperate MonitorState and initalize it everytime? I think the idea of modelling MonitorState as a Map is ugly and not very haskell-y. **What are some better ways of structuring my code** so that I can avoid the Map and/or show that there is some relation between the state of the monitor and a formula?
- Other general comments on improving the code quality.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on performance implications of state monad usage, but it seems like list
[concatenation may be a bottleneck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188286/idiomatic-efficient-haskell-append) (e.g. in `getTemporalSubformulas` or `l ++ [time]` in `update`).

**Minor style notes**

It is common practice to import `Data.Map` and `Data.Set` with alias and to
import main type unqualified. This makes type signatures a bit more concise.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map (Map)

foo :: Int -> Map Int String
foo x = Map.singleton x "hello"
```

---

In `isTemporal` you can use `{}` to match on data constructor without matching
its fields. This is potentially future-proof in case of changing number of
fields in data constructor.

```
isTemporal Since{} = True
isTemporal _       = False
```

---

It may be a bit easier to encode intervals as a pair of bounds:

```
data EndPoint t = Open t | Closed t
type Interval t = (EndPoint t, EndPoint t)

afterStart, beforeEnd :: Ord t => t -> Interval t -> Bool
afterStart t (Open start)   = t >  start
afterStart t (Closed start) = t >= start
beforeEnd  t (Open end)     = t <  end
beforeEnd  t (Closed end)   = t <= end

inInterval, inleqInterval :: Ord t => t -> Interval t -> Bool
inInterval t int = afterStart t int && beforeEnd t int
inleqInterval = beforeEnd
```

It is also may be beneficial to reuse intervals
from [data-interval](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-interval) package.

---

In `iinint`

```
foldr (\psi map -> Data.Map.insert psi [] map) Data.Map.empty subformulas
```

can be rewritten as

```
Map.fromList $ map (,[]) subformulas
```

---

Try to compile with `-Wall` flag, seems like you have a lot of non-exhaustive
pattern matches, which is bad.

For example:

```
  let lphi = case (Data.Map.lookup phi bufffs) of Just l -> l
```

If you are absolutely sure that lookup won't fail here, you can rewrite it with [`Data.Map.!`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:-33-):

```
  let lphi = bufffs `Map.!` phi
```

---

`ddrop` can be rewritten to make it more explicit what parts of the list you are removing:

```
ddrop ls inter tao = case dropWhile f ls of
  [] -> []
  kappa:ls' -> kappa : dropWhile g ls'
  where
     f kappa = not $ inleqInterval (tao - kappa) inter
     g kappa = inInterval (tao - kappa) inter
```

or a bit shorter with the [ViewPatterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#view-patterns) extension

```
ddrop ls inter tao = case dropWhile f ls of
  | dropWhile f ls -> kappa:ls' = kappa : dropWhile g ls'
  | otherwise = []
  where
     f kappa = not $ inleqInterval (tao - kappa) inter
     g kappa = inInterval (tao - kappa) inter
```